# Class-Path Entry in dependency jar causing Glassfish PWC6351 Warning

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, classpath, manifest

In Glassfish 4.1 I have an Enterprise Application running. I have used maven for the ear packaging. The dependency jars are kept inside the ear/lib folder. Among these jars there are some jars which have Class-Path entries in their manifest.

Take an example of `batik-js-1.7.jar` which has `Class-Path: xbean.jar` as it's Manifest entry without the version string. The `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` is in that lib folder. Since this jar has the version string in the file name, the Glassfish is throwing Warning message:
`PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:<path_to_server_ear>/lib/xbean.jar does not exist`.

Now if I remove the version string while packaging the ear by the configuration `<fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>` of `maven-ear-plugin` then for this jar the warning message is not appearing anymore, but it is causing same warning for other jars whose Class-Path entry of Manifest have jar names with version string.

How can I solve this warning message issue? Is there anyway to remove the Class-Path entry from Manifest while maven packaging or tell Glassfish not to scan the Manifest for Class-Path?